# Can Apache rewrite ports in the URI?

Tags: apache, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I've setup a basic proxy for a Cassandra monitoring tool that Datastax wrote called OpsCenter.  The app is a python webserver that listens on 8888/8443.  The app doesn't run as root, so it can't bind on 80/443, so I want to run Apache in front as a proxy/reverse proxy.  The problem I'm running into is that OpsCenter rewrites the URI after each requests, and writes the port.

e.g. https://mydomain.com/ becomes https://mydomain.com:8443/ after each request.  This prevents all future requests from working because 8443 isn't open on the firewall.

**Can Apache remove the port from the URI when returning the response to the client?**

Here's what my proxy config looks like.  I'm doing SSL termination at the Proxy.

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On  # OpsCenter also rewrites the host, which becomes 127.0.0.1 without this.
SSLEngine On
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/cert"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/key"
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN  Off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire Off


ProxyPass /tcp http://127.0.0.1:8888/tcp
ProxyPassReverse /tcp http://127.0.0.1:8888/tcp
ProxyPass /opscenter http://127.0.0.1:8888
ProxyPassReverse /opscenter http://127.0.0.1:8888
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change opscenterd.conf, which for packages is at /etc/opscenter/opscenterd.conf, you can set the port that is listed to, and therefore what it rewrites to as

```
[webserver]
port = 8888
interface = 0.0.0.0
```

This will require that the ports that you are binding to aren't already being used by another process.

Answer (score 0):

- you can set

  ```
  ProxyPreserveHost Off
  ```
- or if you want let it (as me) with:

  ```
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ```

  then you must rewrite it this way:

  ```
  ProxyPass           /    http://127.0.0.1:8888/
  ProxyPassReverse    /    http://127.0.0.1:8888/
  ProxyPassReverse    /    http://example.com:8888/
  ```